# Failed to login after change the email or password of the user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

In my project, I have users and their information stores in Firebase.
After they register I send their data to Firebase like this:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'id': id,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'age': age,
      'status': status,
    };
  }
```

The admin can modify their account info and after apply the modification he submit it and data stored in Firebase like this:

```
 final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('UsersInformation')
                              .get();

                          Map<String, dynamic> userData = {};
                          if (user.name != null) {
                            userData['name'] = user.name;
                          }
                          if (user.id != null) {
                            userData['id'] = user.id;
                          }
                          if (user.email != null) {
                            userData['email'] = user.email;
                          }
                          if (user.password != null) {
                            userData['password'] = user.password;
                          }
                          if (age.zones != null) {
                            userData['zones'] = age.zones;
                          }
                          if (user.status != null) {
                            userData['status'] = user.status;
                          }

                          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('UsersInformation')
                              .doc(querySnapshot.docs[index].id)
                              .update(userData);
```

The problem is when the admin changes the user's email or password and then the user tries to log in with the new email, message appears that the email doesn't exist!! while it exists
or if the admin changes the password for the user, and then the user tries to log in with the new password message appears that the password is wrong!

what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using Firebase Authentication? Or are you managing your own authentication solution with the data in Firestore?

Answer (score 1):

`Firestore` and `Authentication` are two different areas of `Firebase`. Updating your database's data doesn't change your authentication data. You need to use the `FirebaseAuth` module with functions like:

```
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
await user?.updateEmail("janeq@example.com");
await user?.updatePassword(newPassword);
```

You can find the associated documentation for `Flutter` at this page [Manage Users in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users?hl=en&authuser=0#set_a_users_email_address)

If your `admin` user is just another user of the system that you are enforcing this role on, then you need to use the Admin API or provide functionality for them to manually edit the other users data (security rules, cloud functions, etc).

You can find the documenation for this at [Manage Users | Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?hl=en&authuser=0)

Edit: Added more clear code about FirebaseAuth and Admin API

Comment: good I got it, but in my application, the admin is the one who edits users' information, so what do I spouse to do to replace currentUser? I used index and it did not work. like this: Users[index].updateEmail(emailController.text);

Comment: Again, you're trying to use `Firestore` to change the email. Is your `admin` user another user that doesn't have access to the `Firebase` console? If so, then that user should not be able to change that data ever. You should be using the [Admin API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?hl=en&authuser=0). The data in your `UsersCollection` collection has nothing to do with your authentication information.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is when you update the password, you only send the password data back and on receiving this data, firebase replaces all data of the user with only this new password. I think that's why the error user email doesn't exist comes out and also why the password shows as wrong because the user doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do to avoid this problem?

Comment: I think you should watch a similar login application example on YouTube and see how they do it. Or a similar example where user is changing his details. And try to implement that solution in your code.

Comment: I searched on YouTube and GitHub, it didn't solve my problem